# Prove that $S_{n} S_{n-1} < \frac{n^{2a+2}}{(a+1)^2}$ where $S_{n} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{a}$ and $a > -1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality

> I am looking to show the following inequality :
> Let $a > -1$ and $ S_{n} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{a} $, show that for all $n \geq 2 :$
> $$S_{n} S_{n-1} <  \frac{n^{2a+2}}{(a+1)^2} .$$

I tried by comparing each partial sum  with an integral, but unfornaturely I got a RHS bigger than  $ \frac{n^{2a+2}}{(a+1)^2}.$  Maybe the key is a tricky induction but I have no idea how to deal with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I consider $-1<a\le 0$ and $a\ge 1$. By convexity, we have that
$$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {k^a }  \le \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\int_{k - 1/2}^{k + 1/2} {t^a {\rm d}t} }  = \int_{1/2}^{n + 1/2} {t^a {\rm d}t}  \le \int_0^{n + 1/2} {t^a {\rm d}t}  = \frac{1}{{a + 1}}\left( {n + \frac{1}{2}} \right)^{a + 1} 
$$
for all $n\ge 1$. Consequently,
\begin{align*}
\bigg( {\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {k^a } } \bigg)\bigg( {\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n - 1} {k^a } } \bigg) & \le \frac{1}{{(a + 1)^2 }}\left( {\left( {n + \frac{1}{2}} \right)\left( {n - \frac{1}{2}} \right)} \right)^{a + 1} \\ & = \frac{1}{{(a + 1)^2 }}\left( {n^2  - \frac{1}{4}} \right)^{a + 1}  \le \frac{{n^{2a + 2} }}{{(a + 1)^2 }},
\end{align*}
provided $n\ge 2$.

For $0<a<1$, we use the standard inequality between the arithmetic and geometric means, and concavity to obtain
\begin{align*}
\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {k^a } } \right)\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n - 1} {k^a } } \right) & \le \left( {\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n - 1} {k^a }  + \frac{{n^a }}{2}} \right)^2  = \left( {\frac{1}{2} + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n - 1} {\frac{{k^a  + (k + 1)^a }}{2}} } \right)^2 \\ & \le \left( {\frac{1}{2} + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n - 1} {\int_k^{k + 1} {t^a {\rm d}t} } } \right)^2 
 = \left( {\frac{1}{2} + \int_1^n {t^a {\rm d}t} } \right)^2 \\ & = \left( {\frac{n^{a + 1}}{{a + 1}}  + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{{a + 1}}} \right)^2  \le \left( {\frac{n^{a + 1}}{{a + 1}} } \right)^2  = \frac{{n^{2a + 2} }}{{(a + 1)^2 }},
\end{align*}
for $n\ge 2$.